# Filtering Subgrid by Relation in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: filtering, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics, subgrid

This is a test project. I've got an entity named 'Classrooms', and another named 'Students'.

I've got an "1-N" relation defined on Classroom with Students.

The form on Classroom has a SubGrid that is populated by the Students.

What I'm willing to do is to fill the subgrid only with the students in that class. Currently all of the students show up in the subgrid. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance, for any explanations or links to tutorials that I missed on my Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing "Only related fields" under it seemed to do the trick. This is not a perfect explanation, just marking the question closed. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Why is it not a perfect explanation? The "Only related fields" option is there to achieve this functionaility.

Comment: I'm extremely new to both programming and Dynamics CRM, thought there might be a better way with more options.